# How to create a list of checkboxes from seed data passed to a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of clubs and activities (ie band or baseball) that I loaded from a .txt file using seed.rb. I want to create a list of checkboxes in my view where a user can check any activities he/she is a part of. I have been having trouble creating the iteration for the list of activities and I receive a "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error. 
My model is called Activity.

my Controller has @activities = Activity.all and

my view has <% @activities.each do |a| %>

But that line doesn't work. The Activity model has a string attribute called :name if that helps. Anyone have an idea I can try? Thanks!

routes. rb

```
CollegeConnection::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :quizzes
  resources :users
  resources :majors
  resources :activities


  root :to => "users#welcome"
 end

quiz controller:


class QuizzesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!


# GET /quizzes
# GET /quizzes.json

def index
  @quizzes = Quiz.all

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @quizzes }
  end
end

# GET /quizzes/1
# GET /quizzes/1.json
def show
  @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @quiz }
  end
end

# GET /quizzes/new
# GET /quizzes/new.json
def new
  @quiz = Quiz.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @quiz }
  end
end

# GET /quizzes/1/edit
def edit
  @quiz = current_user.quizzes.build(params[:id])
end

# POST /quizzes
# POST /quizzes.json
def create
  @quiz = Quiz.new(params[:quiz])
  @quiz.userName=current_user.name
  @activities = Activity.all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @quiz.save
      format.html { redirect_to @quiz, notice: 'Thank You for Taking the Quiz!.' }
      format.json { render json: @quiz, status: :created, location: @quiz }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @quiz.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PUT /quizzes/1
# PUT /quizzes/1.json

def update
  @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @quiz.update_attributes(params[:quiz])
      format.html { redirect_to @quiz, notice: 'Quiz was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @quiz.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /quizzes/1
# DELETE /quizzes/1.json
def destroy
  @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
  @quiz.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to quizzes_url }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
```

end

_form.html.erb quiz view

```
<%= form_for(@quiz, html: {class: "nice"}) do |f| %>
  <% if @quiz.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@quiz.errors.count, "error") %> 
        prohibited this quiz from being saved:
      </h2>

    <ul>
      <% @quiz.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :q1, "Current/Possible Major" %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select(:q1, Major.all, :name, :name) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :q2, "Activities" %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select(:q2, Activity.all, :name, :name) %>
</div>


<% @activities.each do |a| %> 
<%= a.check_box :active %> 
<%= a.submit "Update" %> 
<% end %>


<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :q3 %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :q3, class: 'input-text' %>
</div> 

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</div>
```

Okay, so I found a partial solution:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :q2, "Activities" %><br />  
  <% for activity in Activity.find(:all) %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag(:q2, activity.name) %> <%=activity.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

It lays out all the checkboxes with the name next to it, however it doesn't set the value as the answer to q2 (the quiz attribute for question two) I think im doing something wrong with the checkboxtag. I tried f.check_box but it won't work either. any help?

Error:

```
NoMethodError in Quizzes#new

Showing /Users/Daniel/Documents/cis196/CollegeConnection/app/views/quizzes/_form.html.erb
where line #24 is raised

undefined method `merge' for "Debate\n":String
Extracted source (around line #24):

21:     <%= f.label :q2, "Activities" %><br />  
22:     <% for activity in Activity.find(:all) %>
23:     <div>
24:        <%= f.check_box(:q2, activity.name) %> <%=activity.name %>
25:     </div>
26:   <% end %>
27:   </div>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/quizzes/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/Daniel/Documents/cis196/CollegeConnection 

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/quizzes/_form.html.erb:24:in `block (2 levels) in      _app_views_quizzes__form_html_erb__435461842904466959_70320063188680'
```

app/views/quizzes/_form.html.erb:22:in `each'
app/views/quizzes/_form.html.erb:22:in`block in _app_views_quizzes__form_html_erb__435461842904466959_70320063188680'
app/views/quizzes/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_quizzes__form_html_erb__435461842904466959_70320063188680'
app/views/quizzes/new.html.erb:6:in`_app_views_quizzes_new_html_erb__735256988922435877_70320063679640'
app/controllers/quizzes_controller.rb:31:in `new'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None

Quiz Model

```
Class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

validates :q1, :presence => true
validates :q2, :presence => true
validates :q3, :presence => true

serialize :q2
```

end

Comment: Post more code, @activities is nil in the view,  so your controller code isn't being called prior to hitting your view.  Post your routes.rb,  and the full controller code and view code,  with their file names.

Comment: For code samples, add four blanks at the beginning of the line.

Comment: alright, i fixed the format. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think is going on.  Your _form partial is a partial because it is probably shared by your create view and your edit view.  The _form partial depends on @activities being initialized.  You've initialized it ONLY in your create action.  Try something like this:

quizzes_controller.rb

```
QuizzesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter load, :only =>[:create, :edit]
  def load
    @activities = Activity.all
  end
end
```

Then you can remove

```
@activities = Activity.all
```

from your create action,  and @activities will be initialized in both your create and edit actions.

UPDATE:

check_box_tag takes 3 (or more) arguments,  the first is the id of element,  the second is the value that will be delivered,  the THIRD is a boolean that if true will cause the check box to be checked.

So now you'll have to post your models and associations  does Quiz 'has_many' activities, etc.

Comment: So that helped. but now i get undefined method `merge' for "Debate\n":String

Comment: post the the complete error message as it shows on the error page that rails generated.  Remember to format it with the four spaces.

Comment: Okay I added my quiz model. Can i just write in has_many :activites     or do I neeed to do migrations for that? Also, do I need to add something else?

Comment: and also, what should my checkbox arguments be?